# How to format a phone number in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

I have a database with table name `student`.

I would like to display the `register_number` and `phone_number` of the student.

The `phone_number` should be in the following format:

```
+91-123-456-7890
```

and if the phone_number is `NULL`, then it should display `N/A`.

The table looks like:

```
R_NO      |     STUDENT_NAME    |  PHONE_NUMBER
-------------------------------------------------------
  1       |      Rajesh         |  9632545123
  2       |      Sridevi        |  9512647359
  3       |      Shiva          |  9632155862
  4       |      HariHaran      |  8426911231
  5       |      Ravi           |  9111558899
  6       |      Pauline        |  NULL
```

Comment: And what about countries with 1 digit international codes and not 2, or (like mine) those with 3 digits? And who's to say that area codes are 3 digits? I live in a country where it varies from (IIRC) 2 - 4...

Comment: This is one case where proper schema definition makes a huge difference. For the future, I would suggest a composite type or a `1 -> n` relationship from students to phone numbers. Not only much more flexible, but presentation issues like the one in this question would be a breeze.

Comment: Breaking the phone number down into country code, area code and number would help with the presentation side as well.

Answer (score 4):

Different areas have differing number of digits in their prefix ([wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes)):

```
COALESCE(CONCAT('+',
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT(phone_number, 1) IN ('1', '7')
      THEN INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(phone_number, 2, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-'), 10, 0, '-')
    WHEN CONVERT(LEFT(phone_number, 2), SIGNED) IN (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 35, 37, 38, 42, 50, 59,
                                                    67, 68, 69, 80, 85, 87, 88, 96, 97, 99)
      THEN INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(phone_number, 4, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 12, 0, '-')
    ELSE   INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(phone_number, 3, 0, '-'), 7, 0, '-'), 11, 0, '-') END), 'N/A')
```

With the query above, all phone numbers will show as `+Country_code-XXX-XXX-XXXX` although each area has specific formatting rules, which vary greatly, so that formatting will look funny for certain regions, such as Australia where formatting is `+54-X-XXXX-XXXX`.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for what I'm doing - I'd normally pull the data out and format it in code but this is just a one-off (for now) report.

Answer (score 1):

One part *could* be handled thus:

```
IFNULL(phone_number, 'N/A');
```

But, really, your formatting requirement is best done in your application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has code for a mask function that works like this:

```
SELECT mask(991234567890, '+##-###-###-####')
-> +99-123-456-7890
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112718/mysql-output-masking-i-e-phone-number-ssn-etc-display-formatting

As for N/A, something like this should work:

```
SELECT IfNull(phone_number, 'N/A')
```

Answer (score -1):

As french citizen, we have different way to write this.

Here is how I show the phone numbers :

```sql
SELECT
    UserName,
    CASE
        WHEN Mobile IS NULL OR Mobile = '' THEN ''
        ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTR(Mobile,1,2), ' ', SUBSTR(Mobile,3,2), ' ', SUBSTR(Mobile,5,2), ' ', SUBSTR(Mobile,7,2), ' ', SUBSTR(Mobile,9,2))
    END as 'Mobile',
FROM Users
```

The result will be like this `01 23 45 67 89`:

| UserName | Mobile |
| --- | --- |
| Some name | 01 23 45 67 89 |
| OtherGuy | 06 54 12 11 42 |

Answer (score -3):

```
select cname
      ,coalesce(concat('+91-',substring(contactNo,1,3),'-',substring(contactNo,4,3),'-',substring(contactNo,7)),'N/A') as Contact_Number
  from company
 order by cname asc;
```

Comment: Perhaps some explanation of what this is doing would be helpful to add?

Comment: It's also nice to try to match up with the OP's table and column names, to make things easier to follow.